# Getting "Access is Denied" on calling GetFileAttributes() for a folder

Tags: windows, winapi

My program (running as administrator) is calling GetFileAttributes() on a directory located in Program Files.

It fails, and GetLastError() returns 0x80070005 ("Access is Denied"). I'm not able to identify how users might end up in this scenario. This folder was created by my application previously. And it works for most of the users but not all.

Questions:

1. How can I simulate "access is denied" for a folder such that GetFileAttributes() function fails?
2. Will running the program with administrator and requesting se_backup_name and se_restore_name resolve this issue?

I tried removing users from security tab still GetFileAttributes did not fail.

Issue is reproduced on Win 7, 8, 10.

Comment: Show your code. Perhaps there is a simple mistake in it.

Comment: Getting a COM `HRESULT` value for the last error after calling `GetFileAttibutes` is unexpected. It has the right facility code (7), but I'd expect a bare Windows `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5).

Comment: `GetFileAttributes` never set last error to `80070005`. this last error from another component

Comment: To prevent a user from reading the attributes of a file or directory, first move it to a directory that the user isn't allowed to list, since otherwise the right to read attributes would be granted implicitly. Then add an ACE to the file's DACL that denies the user the right to read attributes.

Comment: If an open is flagged for backup intent and SeBackupPrivilege is enabled, then the I/O manager grants generic read and execute access, plus the right to access the system access control list. `GetFileAttributes` (i.e. NTAPI `NtQueryAttributesFile`) does open with backup intent, so enabling backup privilege should allow an administrator to read file attributes in most cases. I don't think it grants an admin access to a file at system integrity level that disallows read-up, but that's not normal.

Comment: However, requiring users to run a program with admin access is legacy behavior. Non-static data directories should be created where users can access them, either under `%ProgramData%` (with a custom DACL that grants the required access to all users or a set of groups) or per-user in `%LocalAppData%` or `%AppData%`.

Comment: The more mystifying sources of an "access denied" error on a folder are the ones caused by the folder being deleted.  But another process still having a handle opened on the folder, typically because it is the default working directory or being observed with FileSystemWatcher.  That prevents the folder from being removed from the file system and  puts the folder in a "delete pending" state.  Any subsequent access to it will be greeted with access denied.

Comment: @HansPassant, it wouldn't be due to the working directory since Windows doesn't open it with delete sharing. A race condition along these lines that I've seen reported is due to Explorer opening directories with delete sharing and watching them via `ReadDirectoryChangesExW`. It gets notified when the directory is deleted and quickly closes its handle, but not necessarily before another program tries to access the directory.

Comment: Can you show us the code that created the folder?  Perhaps there's something funky about its security attributes.  Explorer's Security tab might tell us more, or better yet the output from `icacls`.  @eryksun Agree (about cwd). My experience is that you can't delete it.

Comment: Sameer, I explained in two comments above why your attempts to disallow read-attributes access failed and how to test it properly, and whether and how to use SeBackupPrivilege to gain access. Does that answer the question overall, or are you still looking for the exact reason this problem ocurred? If so, please show the security descriptor of both the directory and its parent directory, preferably in detail using Sysinternals [AccessChk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/accesschk), e.g. `accesschk -dvl path\to\dir`.

Answer (score -3):

I know the topic is really old, but I faced the same problem yesterday, and I've found a solution; it's maybe not the best but may be helpful.

This problem comes from a lack of rights with the account used to get the file/dll SCCM needs to use/install. See this [topic](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e518bb62-d35e-470e-8252-e58be7de4338/update-from-1906-to-1910-failed) in technet for more informations.

Just go into *security* and change the right about *everyone* to *full control*. It's risky because, after that, everyone can get to the folder. You can remove it after the update.